# {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I used jboss 5.1

and I used soap webservice in my project.

most of  time the web service works
correctly

but sometime I have this error :

```
  faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readHeadersFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:583)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:143)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.web.service.BalanceServiceSoapBindingStub.getInfo(BalanceServiceSoapBindingStub.java:550)
    at com.web.manager.impl.TestManagerImpl.newEmp(TestManagerImpl.java:893)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

this is my soap client code :

```
  BalanceServiceServiceLocator balance = new BalanceServiceServiceLocator();
            BalanceServiceSoapBindingStub service = new BalanceServiceSoapBindingStub(new URL(
                        balance.getBalanceServiceAddress()), balance);

   EmployeeEntity employeeDetail = service.getInfo(matricule);
```

I think that I should increase the timeout and I try with this code :

```
  BalanceServiceServiceLocator balance = new BalanceServiceServiceLocator();
                BalanceServiceSoapBindingStub service = new BalanceServiceSoapBindingStub(new URL(
                            balance.getBalanceServiceAddress()), balance);

org.apache.axis.client.Stub s =  service;
            s.setTimeout(new Integer(1000*120));

       EmployeeEntity employeeDetail = service.getInfo(matricule);
```

is it the best way to resolve the problem

**updated :**

sometimes after increasing the timeout I solved my problem
but sometimes the same error appeared again : faultString: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

note that soap webservice client and server is in two different network range

is it problem of network, firewall
and is it possible to make a configuration in the firewall to accept HTTP traffic,

or how can i modify my code in order to handle this exception meaning 
I display in my application  that I have network problem 
 after for example 30 second without getting the response

Comment: Apparently, your call to `BalanceServiceSoapBindingStub.getInfo` is taking more than the default [60 seconds](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/http.html). If you don't have access to the stubs you're accessing and can't figure out the reason why the timeout is being triggered then, yes, increasing your connection timeout may be the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: thank you for your response , sometimes the same error appeared again : faultString: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out ,  I don't know the error source, and I want to modify my code in order to handle this exception

Comment: For that you should use a `try-catch` in order to deal with the exception that's being thrown and then treat it according to your needs.